# Real-time JPG-frame streaming through a network

Tags: android, image-processing, networking, unity-game-engine

I am developing an Android application with Unity3D (C#) that captures frames from the camera (~30fps) and sends them to a computer on a network. The frames received by the computer will then be processed with an OpenCV-based program (C++). I managed to implement this using UDP socket (also tried TCP but some frames get lost sometimes). Later, I found out that some networks stop UDP packets for security reasons (like inside my company), so I would like to generalise the communication by creating a different interface, e.g. via HTTP POST. Will this make sense? I don't have much experience with HTTP requests and I was wandering whether this approach will be similar the TCP-socket case, that wasn't successful.

Are there other communication means that can guarantee performance like UDP, but by making the communication at a higher level?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of socket protocols... TCP and UDP. HTTP is an application protocol that is run on the data received over a TCP socket. So you cannot replace TCP or UDP with HTTP. You will use HTTP with a TCP or UDP socket.

Now there is something troubling with your post... TCP sockets are by far the more reliable. It does not make sense that frames get lost when using TCP, since TCP essentially guarantees that you will get all of your data out.

With UDP, on the other hand, you will often find that many packets get dropped. Actually, for video streaming that is not a totally bad thing. For video streaming, you want to reduce the latency as much as possible. TCP has to do a lot of error checking to ensure that your packets don't get dropped, and so TCP is much slower than UDP. Hence for video streaming, you will typically use UDP.

In any event, there are much more efficient libraries for streaming video than simply trying to implement your own with UDP and jpeg frames. I would recommend you search for one that meets your platform and language needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I meant with UDP vs. HTTP was, how to send frames at a high-speed rate by moving from a low level, as UDP, to high level, as HTTP, while maintaining a good rate performance. The reason of moving to a higher level is to become independent from problems like a blocked UDP network. In my specific case, I would like to stick to streaming of single frames, one-by-one and one after the other, as opposed to a video stream. As I wrote above, I am using C# on the device and I am open to use any language (e.g. C#, C/C++, Java, Python) on the server that receives the frames.

Comment: If you cannot use UDP sockets, then you will be using TCP sockets. It is not necessary to use HTTP on top of that, unless you really want to. In any case, which streaming protocol is the best is another question entirely. You should google around for something like "open source video streaming protocol" to see which one best suits your needs, although I believe most solutions will use UDP sockets under the hood.

Comment: Ok. I will try to find a workaround to this issue using TCP.